# Calculator of string expressions. Issue with power-opperation

Tags: c, recursion

There is a task, to write calculator, which recieves strings cosisting of:

- chars '0'-'9',
- brackest '(', ')',
- chars '+', '-', '*', '/', '^',

and performing following ops:

- addition
- substraction
- multiplication
- integer division
- power.

Arcitecture of solution should include recursive descent

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

jmp_buf begin;
char curlex;

void getlex(void);
int expr(void);
int add_sub(void);
int mult_div(void);
int power(void);
void error();

int main() {
    int result;
    setjmp(begin);
    printf("==>");
    getlex();
    result=expr();
    if ( curlex != '\n') error();
    printf("\n%d\n",result);
    return 0;
}

void getlex() {
    while ( ( curlex=getchar()) == ' ');
}

void error(void) {
    printf("\nERROR!\n");
    while(getchar()!='\n');
    longjmp(begin,1);
}

int expr() {
    int e=add_sub();
    while (curlex == '+' || curlex == '-')
        if (curlex == '+')
        {getlex(); e+=add_sub();}
        else if (curlex == '-')
        {getlex(); e-=add_sub();}
    return e;
}

int add_sub() {

    int a=mult_div();
    while (curlex == '*' || curlex == '/')
        if (curlex == '*')
        {getlex(); a*=mult_div();}
        else if (curlex == '/')
        {getlex(); a/=mult_div();}
    return a;
}

int mult_div() {
    int a=power();
    while (curlex == '^')
    {getlex(); for(int k=0;k<power(); k++, a*=power());}
    return a;
}

int power() {
    int m;
    switch(curlex){
        case '0':
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9': m= curlex-'0'; break;
        case '(': getlex(); m=expr();
                  if ( curlex == ')') break;
        default : error();
    }

    getlex();
    return m;
}
```

Code performs almost everything mentioned, except power-operation. I can't find a bug. There is also an issue with right association of power operation. That means expression 3^1^2 gives 9, but should give 3.

Please help!

Comment: C and C++ are two very different languages, please don't spam irrelevant tags and only use the one for the language you're actually working with.

Comment: As for your problem, now might be a good time to learn how to use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through your code line by line while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: If you want others to read your code, then please adopt a conventional coding style. In addition, there are _lots_ of very bad practices in this code, so when you get it working I strongly recommend to post it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @mch
right associated power means 3^(1^2) = 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the full solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

jmp_buf begin;
char curlex;

void getlex(void); 
int expr(void); 
int add_sub(void); 
int mult_div(void); 
int power(void);
void error(); 

int main() {
    int result; 
    setjmp(begin); 
    printf("==>"); 
    getlex();      
    result=expr(); 
    if ( curlex != '\n') error(); 
    printf("\n%d\n",result);
    return 0;
}

void getlex() {
while ( ( curlex=getchar()) == ' '); 
}


void error(void) {
    printf("\nОШИБКА!\n");
    while(getchar()!='\n');
    longjmp(begin,1);
}


int expr() {
    int e=add_sub(); 
    while (curlex == '+' || curlex == '-') 
        if (curlex == '+')
        {getlex(); e+=add_sub();} 
        else if (curlex == '-')
        {getlex(); e-=add_sub();} 
    return e;
}

int add_sub() {
    while (curlex == '*' || curlex == '/') 
        if (curlex == '*')
        {getlex(); a*=mult_div();} 
        else if (curlex == '/')
        {getlex(); a/=mult_div();} 
    return a;
}


int mult_div() {

    int a=power(), res=1;
    while (curlex == '^') 
        {getlex(); 
        int m=mult_div();
        for(int k=0 ;k<m; k++, res*=a); 
        return res;} 
    return a;
}

int power() {
    int m; 

    switch(curlex){ 
    case '0': 
    case '1': 
    case '2': 
    case '3': 
    case '4': 
    case '5':
    case '6': 
    case '7': 
    case '8': 
    case '9': m= curlex-'0'; break;
    case '(': getlex(); m=expr(); 
        if ( curlex == ')') break; 
    default : error();
    }
    
getlex();
return m;
}
```

It works with right-assotiated power-operation.

Comment: Solution of another user didn't help me, didn't even give me any idea, perhaps because of my own lack of programming intuition or feeleng. So, I wrote my own option of correct solution and published it.

Comment: Moreover, the implementation of short concepts usually published is not easier than the understanding of concepts as part of complete programs. Both is not easy and useful to develop programming skills

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `power()` too often in `mult_div()`. Once you have a value returned by `power()` you should calculate the power and continue:

```
int mult_div() {
    int a=power();
    while (curlex == '^') 
    {
        getlex();
         a = calc_power(a, power());
    }
    return a;
}
```

To make it easier I used a helper function to calculate the power:

```
int calc_power(int a, int b)
{
    int res = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++) res *= a;
    return res;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/n4KhWx6j1

`curlex` should be an `int`, because that's what `getchar` returns: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar